# Practical Transformer output

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am a junior on Electrical engineering, on one of my experiment, I have yet found any explanation for this:

Is there any possibility that a **practical** transformer would produce a **zero** real power on the secondary side, which measured to be *-j3.5x10 VAR*? Given that the measured complex power on the primary side is *(1.8 + j1.5)x10 VAR* and the transformer is not stepping up or down. If yes, why and on what conditions? Any explanation or thoughts would definitely help, and thank you.

Comment: you mean that the output power (at the secondary) is 35 VAR? this is doable by connecting an inductor the the secondary, which will not consume any real power, but only reactive power. Now, in real-life we obviously have some small resistances, which will consume real power, but we can consider them next to zero. PS. for EE subject also try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see, I believe you had give me a direction to approach this. I didn't connect a inductor on the secondary side, instead, it was a short transmission lines(under 80km), therefore I suspect the 0 real power is caused by it. Thank you.